# Как сделать полноэкранное окно в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать рабочее окно программы по размерам монитора, чтобы оно само раздвигалась во всю ширину?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выставляйте в свойствах формы, `WindowState = wsMaximized`.

Comment: А он на разных разрешениях будет растягивать все кнопки и  остальное под монитор?

Comment: "Растягивать все кнопки" - что вы имеете ввиду? Если у элементов заданы `Anchors` и `Align`, то да, они будут держаться нужных сторон и растягиваться.